# Junk values - Inheritance in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, virtual, abstract

I have a class as follows:

```
class base
{
    protected:
        int x;
        int y;
        int z;
    public:
        base(int x, int y, int z)
        {
            x = x;
            y = y;
            z = z;
        }
        virtual void show();
};
```

I derive a class from the above as:

```
class derived : protected base
{
    public:
        int a;
        int b;
        int c;
        derived(int a, int b, int x, int y, int z) : base(x, y, z) //initialising the base class members as well
        {
            cout<<a<<b<<x<<y<<z; //works fine
            a = a;
            b = b;
        }
        void show()
        {
            cout<<a<<b<<x<<y<<z; //show junk values            
        }
        //some data members and member functions
};
```

In main(), I use:

```
    derived d(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

    d.show();
```

The data members appear to have legal values inside the constructor. However, when I use a similar function, i.e. with the same visibility mode, junk values seem to appear.

Comment: are you supposed to call base constructor in derived as `base(x, y, z)`?

Comment: @Vikdor: Yep. Corrected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
a = a;
b = b;
```

should be

```
this->a = a;
this->b = b;
```

or, even better, use an initializer list:

```
derived(int a, int b, int x, int y, int z) : a(a), b(b),  base(x,y,z) 
{
    cout<<a<<b<<x<<y<<z; //works fine
}
```

what you're doing is self-assigning the parameter, so the members don't get set.

Comment: Thanks. That made it. Any insight into why this way would be really helpful.

Comment: @KuttuV in the answer - you named your parameters the same as your members, so the members get hidden unless you qualify them.

Answer (score 3):

You never initialize your member variables. `a=a;` will assign to the local variable `a` (the parameter), not the member variable. It should be `this->a=a;`. The same for the other members.